# Cant press multiple keys on Linux (ONLY) while gaming

Tags: linux, keyboard

I've been using windows 10 and everything was fine with my keyboard - so I don't believe it is a keyboard issue.

When using Linux (Zorin OS 16), and when, for example, I am in Minecraft, and I press W, A, Shift simultaneously (to sprint diagonally) some of the keys don't work. Most of the time its A (this results in me sprinting forward instead of diagonally)

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: sounds like "keyboard ghosting." This varies by keyboard.

Comment: @Yorik as i said in the beginning of the post, i don't believe its the keyboard as this doesn't happen with a Windows 10 install + doesn't happen when virtualizing Windows 10 inside the same Linux install